# javascript function reloads page upon completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

I have a simple javascript program that runs onclick of an image.

However, whenever I clicked the image, the page reloaded.

After a lot of debugging I found that the page doesn't reload until right as the script completes.

There are several setTimeouts in the code, but I noticed the page was reloading instantly. I even changed these timeouts to 15000 milliseconds, but it still reloads immediately.

I am using jquery, if it makes any difference.

I also want a different result from the program every time you click it, so that each time you click it a different script runs and a some text changes in a specific order. I did this by changing the onclick attribute of the images in each script to the name of the next script, so that script one would switch onclick to script two, and so on. I set a timeout on these switches so that one click doesn't race through every single script. script two isn't running, so that much works.

my code:

```
function getSounds() {
    console.log("script. initiated");
    $("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("Now, Wait until the file is done downloading and click below again.");
    console.log("new message");
    $("#soundwebGetSoundA").attr('href',"");
    console.log("href eliminated");
    setTimeout($("#soundwebGetSoundImg").attr('onclick','findFile()'),2000); 
    console.log("onclick to findFile()");

}

function findFile(){
    console.log("FINDFILE")
    $("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("Find the file(it's probably in your downloads), copy the path of the file (usually at the top of the file explorer) and paste in it the box below.  Then, make sure there is a '/' at the end of the path and type 'Linkiness.txt' (case sensitive, without quotes) at the end.  Once you have all that stuff typed, click the icon again.");
    console.log("FIND IT, DARN IT!!");
    $("#soundwebGetSoundPathInput").css("opacity",1);
    console.log("diving into reader");
    setTimeout($("#soundwebGetSoundImg").attr('onclick','readFile()'),1000); 
}
function readFile(){
    console.log("loading...");
    $("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("loading...");
    if(document.getElementById("soundwebGetSoundPathInput").value.length == 0){
        setTimeout($("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("Please fill in Path!"),1000);
        setTimeout(findFile(),2000);
    }

}
```

and the HTML that's linked to,

```
<a id = "soundwebGetSoundA" href = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1ynhHZihlL241FNZEar6ibzEdhHcWJ1qXKaxMUKM-DpE&exportFormat=txt">
                    <img onclick = "getSounds();" class = "soundwebImgResize" src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glypho-music-and-sound/64/music-note-sound-circle-512.png" id = "soundwebGetSoundImg"/>
                </a>
```

Thanks for any help,
Lucas N.

Comment: You've got the image inside an anchor tag with an href. What do you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I am not very good with website-building.  should I stuff the href on the image?

Comment: Do you want the link that's wrapped around the image to work as a link? I'm not clear why it's there.

Comment: The link is to a download that I only want to download the first time you click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want clicking the image to cause the anchor tag to load the href, then move the image tag outside of the anchor tag.

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `setTimeout` correctly. You should be passing in a function not a statement. So, for example, instead of

```
setTimeout($("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("Please fill in Path!"),1000);
setTimeout(findFile(),2000);
```

you should use

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#soundwebGetSoundDirections").html("Please fill in Path!") },1000);
setTimeout(findFile,2000);
```

I think the same goes for setting the `onclick` attribute but I've never tried dynamically changing an `onclick` attribute like that.

Since you're already using jQuery you could try using `.on('click'...` and `.off('click'...` if your current setup isn't working.

Comment: Hmm... I tried all that, but nothing changed. It's still reloading.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `href` (for testing purposes)?